# Django template not receiving value from URL

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

Good day Django experts and enthusiasts!

I have the following situation (source code is at the end of this post):

I have one template that is used by DetailView for **post** model (i.e. show detail of particular instance of post). In this template, I have context_object_name **post** in the template - that object has an ID. In this DetailView, there is an URL link to another CreateView template. That create view is for **comment** model. There is foreign key relationship between **post** and **comment** - one post can have 0 - more comments.

When I click on DetailView for **post**, I have a link for CreateView for comment. When user is writing a comment for post and hits *save button*, I need to have post.id available in the template in the template for CreateView (I would like to send it as hidden field in form for comment so that **comment** model has post.id available in save() method - that would cover the need for foreign key when saving **comment**).

Now to the merit of my problem:

I would like to send a post.id from DetailView template to CreateView template (so I can use it as hidden form). Problem is, post.id is not received by template for CreateView for comment. Source code covering my needs is as follows:

Template for DetailView (of **post**), namely the url linking to CreateView (for **comment**):

```
<a  class="btn btn-danger" href="{% url 'commentpost' post_id=post.id %}">Reagovat</a>
```

A row for application level urls.py taking care of `commentpost` URL:

```
path('commentpost/<int:post_id>/',CommentPostView.as_view(),name='commentpost')
```

I was thinking that template for commentpost URL should have `{{ post_id }}` value available ... however, than one comes empty to the commentpost template -> a row in template for commentpost:
`<tr><td>ID:{{ post_id }}</td></tr>`.

CreateView for comment:

```
class CommentPostView(CreateView):
    model = Comment
    context_object_name = 'comment'
    form_class = NewCommentForm
    template_name = 'new_comment.html'
```

Model for Comment:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.CharField(max_length = 100, choices = DEPARTMENTS)
    date_sent = models.DateTimeField()
    text = models.TextField(max_length = 255)
```

Basically the flow should be as follows: 
1) DetailView template sending `post_id` -> 2) urls.py taking care of the `post_id` value - calling the correct view 3) View rendering the template and template receiving `post_id` value.

I am 100% sure the `post_id` value in step 1) is not empty. The URL for step 1) i.e. DetailView looks as follows: `http://192.168.56.101:8080/detailpost/1360`

Does any of you have an idea what am I missing?

Thank you very much in advance for any suggestions, take care.

Comment: `post_id` will be available in the `CommentPostView` and since you have the `post_id` in the `create view` you won't need to have it in the template, however, to have it in the template you need to pass it with the `context data`. Can you please show me your CreateView?

Comment: Hello Radico, the CreateView has been added to my original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_context_data` method will make `post_id` available in the template:

```
class CommentPostView(CreateView):
    model = Comment
    context_object_name = 'comment'
    form_class = NewCommentForm
    template_name = 'new_comment.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['post_id'] = self.kwargs.get('post_id', None)
        return context
```

Comment: Thank you Radico, I have achieved what I needed with your help. You said I don't need to have the post_id in the template, I can manipulate the post_id in the View. However, that concept is not clear to me yet. Here's why: the method save() where I can influence an interaction with database relates to Model, not view. How can I manipulate the storage of data in View? It will be sufficient to point me towards help or other resource. No need to explain it here thoroughly. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome. Just import the model to your view and you will have the full control of reacting with the database, I suggest you to go through django [documentations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/) which is the best resource ever.

Answer (score 0):

@Radico's answer is good. Another approach would be to get the object in the view (that's if you need other fields beside id). In the template you would access it by `object.id`

```
def get_object(self, queryset=None):
    return get_object_or_404(Post, pk=self.kwargs['post_id'])
```

Comment: Thank you. I have used Radico's answer as a solution. Your answer helped me as well. Apparently, I have some Django knowledge gaps that I need to fill. I will try to proceed with the project as far as possible on my own. Should I have other questions or problems I am unable to resolve on my own, I would kindly ask this awesome community for help again.